# Cast fixed date into multiple time zones

Tags: presto

I have a *fixed* date (say, `'2019-10-01'`) that I'd like to cast into multiple time zones according to the value in a `time_zone` column like so:

```
values (1, 'Asia/Jakarta'), (2, 'Asia/Manila')
-- 1 Asia/Jakarta
-- 2 Asia/Manila
```

It's certainly possible to store a column with per-row time zones:

```
values (timestamp '2019-10-01' at time zone 'Asia/Jakarta')
union all
values (timestamp '2019-10-01' at time zone 'Asia/Manila')
-- 2019-10-01 07:00:00.000 Asia/Jakarta
-- 2019-10-01 08:00:00.000 Asia/Manila
```

But I can't see a way to get this done effectively.

From the [datetime help page](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) I see two avenues:

1. Using `AT TIME ZONE` doesn't work -- requires a string literal, *not* a column:

```
select timestamp '2019-10-01' AT TIME ZONE tz
from (values ('Asia/Jakarta'), ('Asia/Manila')) t(tz)
-- line 1:44: no viable alternative at input 'TIME ZONE tz'
```

2. Using `from_unixtime` doesn't work -- only works starting from the unix time, but this is a Catch 22 for the problem at hand -- to get the correct UTC times is exactly the goal.

Is there some other approach that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`at_timezone`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#at_timezone) which is a dynamic equivalent of `AT TIME ZONE <literal>`.

```
presto:default> SELECT id, at_timezone(CAST('2019-10-01' AS date), tz)
             -> FROM (VALUES (1, 'Asia/Jakarta'), (2, 'Asia/Manila')) t(id, tz);
 id |                _col1
----+--------------------------------------
  1 | 2019-10-01 05:00:00.000 Asia/Jakarta
  2 | 2019-10-01 06:00:00.000 Asia/Manila
(2 rows)
```

Related: for changing one zoned date time to a different zone (while preserving point in time), you'd use [`with_timezone`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#with_timezone). So make sure the `at_timezone` gives you the semantics you want.

(tested on Presto 324)

Comment: Seems there's also a Hive function available: `to_utc_timestamp` which accepts a `tz` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extremely awkward approach; I hope there's something better (in particular, it's not robust to timezone offsets changing over time, e.g. for daylight savings):

```
select
    from_iso8601_timestamp(concat('2019-10-01', 'T00:00:00.000+', h, ':', m)) t
from (
  select 
      -- a bit hackier: use regexp_extract(to_iso8601(ts), '[+].*'),
      --   which also allows you to un-nest this part of the query
      lpad(cast(timezone_hour(ts) as varchar), 2, '0') h, 
      lpad(cast(timezone_minute(ts) as varchar), 2, '0') m
  from (
    -- easier to write 0, BUT, this is more robust to change
    --   of timezone definitions since 1970 (relatively common)
    select from_unixtime(to_unixtime(current_timestamp), tz) ts
    from ( values ('Asia/Jakarta'), ('Asia/Manila')) t(tz)
  )
)
-- 2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 +07:00
-- 2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 +08:00
```

Given this lack of robustness, there should be a roughly equivalent approach using `difftime` as well.